How to use singleton SwiftData models
I am working on a project including SwiftData, and have the following 2 models (please note only relevant parts are shown):
Chip
(like an electronics chip)
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


@Model
class Chip: Identifiable {
        
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    
    var name: String
    var detail: String
    private var _color: Color.Resolved
    var color: Color {
        ...
    }
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var topPins: [Pin]?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var bottomPins: [Pin]?
    var imageData: Data?
    
    var numTopPins: Int { topPins?.count ?? 0 }
    var numBottomPins: Int { bottomPins?.count ?? 0 }
    var numPins: Int { numTopPins + numBottomPins }
    
    init(name: String, detail: String, color: Color, topPins: [Pin], bottomPins: [Pin]) {
        ...
    }
    
    init(name: String, detail: String, color: Color, imageData: Data) {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
    
}

Pin:
(The pins on the chip)
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


@Model
class Pin: Identifiable, Equatable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    
    var name: String
    var detail: String
    var pinNum: Int
    var chip: Chip?
    
    init(name: String = "New pin...", detail: String = "Pin detail...", pinNum: Int) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.detail = detail
        self.pinNum = pinNum
    }
    
    ...
}


extension Chip {
    static let ne555 = Chip(
        name: "NE555",
        detail: "The 555 timer IC is an integrated circuit used in a variety of timer, delay, pulse generation, and oscillator applications.",
        color: .randomSystem(),
        topPins: [
            Pin(name: "VCC", detail: "Connect to logic high", pinNum: 8),
            Pin(name: "Discharge", detail: "Discharge the timer", pinNum: 7),
            Pin(name: "Threshold", detail: "Threshold of the voltage", pinNum: 6),
            Pin(name: "Control", detail: "Controls the voltage. Set to logic 0", pinNum: 5),
        ], bottomPins: [
            Pin(name: "Ground", detail: "Set to logic 0", pinNum: 1),
            Pin(name: "Trigger", detail: "The trigger for the timer", pinNum: 2),
            Pin(name: "Output", detail: "Outputs to another system", pinNum: 3),
            Pin(name: "Reset", detail: "Sets the output to logic 0", pinNum: 4),
        ]
    )
}

Main entry
@main
struct Pinout_makerApp: App {
    @State private var c = Chip.ne555
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ChipDetailView(chip: c)
                .modelContainer(for: [Chip.self, Pin.self])
        }
    }
}


The error:
When I run the code I get an error:
SwiftData/PersistentModel.swift:327: Fatal error: Unable to find a container with entity Chip

I have tried to reproduce the error in other projects and from doing so, figured out it is my use of @State private var c = Chip.ne555 in the main app. I am accessing a model's singleton instance outside of a context and the model's container (like a database file) has not yet been created.
To try to resolve this issue I created a fetch request for it separately, however it still cannot work.
@main
struct Pinout_makerApp: App {
    @State private var chip: Chip?
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if let chip = chip {
//                ChipDetailView(chip: chip)
                Text(chip.name)
                    .modelContainer(for: [Chip.self, Pin.self])
                    .onAppear {
                        let request = FetchDescriptor<Chip>()
                        let data = try? modelContext.fetch(request)
                        self.chip = data?.first ?? .ne555
                    }
            } else {
                ContentUnavailableView("Could not fetch chip", systemImage: "memorychip")
            }
        }
    }
}

However I still cannot get it to work. Why is this? I used Paul's article to give me this code.

Why do you need to inject the Chip object into the ChipDetailView, can’t you load it inside the view instead?

SwiftData is the wrong tool for this if you want a singleton use Observable if not use the database as a source of truth

Also State with the new Observation creates a deep copy and disconnects the model from its source

As other commenters said, why do you want to use a Swift Data model here? They should not be used for singletons. This might be a XY Problem.

As far as the linked article you should note that Pauls code is executed in the ContentView which is after the ModelContainier has been created

Hi @Joakin, thanks for your replies. So what is the difference in creating the chip in one view and passing it into other views that use it like how I do, than just creating it in the views that use it?

@loremipsum, please explain why I don't use State with Observation. If I have a view model, for example, @Observable class VM { }, then I create and use it like @State var vm = VM(), so if the Model is an observable object, I should still use State?

@loremipsum furthermore, I want some default objects in memory that the user can start off with and edit/delete.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-pre-populate-an-app-with-an-existing-swiftdata-database

Hi, thank you so much for directing me to him!! If you paste that as an answer I can mark it as the solution
